# DevExpress TreeList View with Database

Tags: c#, treelistview

i am currently developing a project and i was stock with treelistview of devexpress what i want is that i have a 3 tables namely Category, Product, Size in my database..
and i want a view like this in my database to represent as my inventory form.

- represent as node 1 COVERALL(CATEGORY)
- represent as node 2 APLAYA(PRODUCT)

  ### > represents as node 3 SMALL ETC (SIZES)

### | Product Category | | |

### * COVERALL | | |

### - APLAYA | PRODUCTS -IN | PRODUCTS OUT | TOTAL

### >SMALL | 120 | 50 | 70

### >LARGE | 130 | 40 | 90

### >MEDIUM | 140 | 40 | 140

### >EXTRALARGE | 180 | 30 | 150

that's why i want to do with my application through the treelistview tool..
please help me .. i really nid it..

thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

If you are developing your application in WPF, you can follow the guide as outlined in

[DevExpress Online Documentation](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#wpf/CustomDocument9933)

For winforms, please look [here](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument5561).

Comment: i am creating a Windows form application.. how can i achieve that layout oliver?

Comment: please see the link in my answer.